# Using ODBC to connect to SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: c++, odbc, codeblocks

I'm on a W32 machine trying to get a connection with a DB. For that purpose, I tried starting testing an example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

using namespace std;

void show_error(unsigned int handletype, const SQLHANDLE& handle){
    SQLCHAR sqlstate[1024];
    SQLCHAR message[1024];
    if(SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(handletype, handle, 1, sqlstate, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
        cout<<"Message: "<<message<<"\nSQLSTATE: "<<sqlstate<<endl;
}

int main(){

    SQLHANDLE sqlenvhandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlconnectionhandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlstatementhandle;
    SQLRETURN retcode;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlenvhandle))
        goto FINISHED;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlenvhandle,SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
        goto FINISHED;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlenvhandle, &sqlconnectionhandle))
        goto FINISHED;

    SQLCHAR retconstring[1024];
    switch(SQLDriverConnect (sqlconnectionhandle,
                NULL,
                (SQLCHAR*)"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost, 1433;DATABASE=MyDatabase;UID=sa;PWD=Admin-123;",
                SQL_NTS,
                retconstring,
                1024,
                NULL,
                SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)){
        case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
            show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
            break;
        case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
        case SQL_ERROR:
            show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
            goto FINISHED;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlconnectionhandle, &sqlstatementhandle))
        goto FINISHED;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLExecDirect(sqlstatementhandle, (SQLCHAR*)"select * from testtable", SQL_NTS)){
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle);
        goto FINISHED;
    }
    else{
        char name[64];
        char address[64];
        int id;
        while(SQLFetch(sqlstatementhandle)==SQL_SUCCESS){
            SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 1, SQL_C_ULONG, &id, 0, NULL);
            SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 2, SQL_C_CHAR, name, 64, NULL);
            SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 3, SQL_C_CHAR, address, 64, NULL);
            cout<<id<<" "<<name<<" "<<address<<endl;
        }
    }

FINISHED:
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle );
    SQLDisconnect(sqlconnectionhandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlenvhandle);

}
```

The problem is that I get MANY problems when trying to compile, regarding undeclared types, for example:

```
'SQLHANDLE' has not been declared
'SQLHDESC' was not declared in this scope
```

I've linked to the `libodbccpp32.a` and `libodbc32.a` libraries already. What is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error seems to indicate that you didn't include the odbc headers that describe the sqlhandle/sqlhdesc.  I think it's in ntodbc.h.

Comment: Do you have any idea of where I can get that header?

Comment: Looks like that one was specific to the Sybase SDK I was using.  Here's a list of the microsoft ones.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713603%28v=VS.85%29.aspx.  It's actually sqltypes.h that's the microsoft sdk one.  Here's where I've installed it C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Vc7\PlatformSDK\Include.  Are there any more details in your compile errors since you've included that one?  What's you include path look like?

Comment: Actually pretty much all the errors are derived from those ones and somehow the same ("error: 'SQLHDESC' was not declared in this scope"). The include path is the one to the mingw headers which include every one of these. I fail to see an include file error in the logs.

Comment: In fact, I have found that adding the header stdafx fixes this. But the problem was the order I included the paths (which is strange because they were this way in the example). I'll include the way it should be to avoid problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found with stdafx.h header that the include order should be instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

ordering header files does not matter. Just ensure that your project contains in its properties the following include directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include
```

where are found (*a priori*):

```
windows.h
sqlext.h
sqltypes.h
sql.h
```

This suffices in making your commands recognized and compile without any problem.

Answer (score -1):

just change include declarations like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
```