# How to connect to SQL Server in C++

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008, odbc

I'm trying to connect to `SQL Server 2008` with `ODBC` driver, I have searched around but didn't find much. Also, I tried the source at [Using ODBC to connect to SQL SERVER 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345110/using-odbc-to-connect-to-sql-server-2008) but I received this message:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I'm using this connection string:

```
DRIVER={Sql Client};
SERVER=WIN-QNPAH3SE4CK\SQLSRV,1433;
DATABASE=dummy;
UID=sa;
PWD=sasasasa;
Trusted_Connection=no;
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you created an ODBC datasource pointing to your db on your system?

Comment: To configure a data source go to Control Panel / System and Security / Administrative Tools / Data Sources (ODBC).  Note there is a 32-bit and a 64-bit version of the ODBC manager and you need to use the one that matches your code.

Answer (score 5):

In your connection string replace the **{SQL Client}** with **{SQL Server}**

Edit:
That's why it's always important to post the code...

You can't do this cast:
**(SQLWCHAR*)**"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=WIN-QNPAH3SE4CK\SQLSRV,1433;DATABASE=dummy;UID=sa;PWD=sasasasa;Trusted_Connection=no;"

Switch it to something like this:
(SQLWCHAR*)**TEXT**("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=WIN-QNPAH3SE4CK\SQLSRV,1433;DATABASE=dummy;UID=sa;PWD=sasasasa;Trusted_Connection=no;")