# Copy and paste images on the from while excecuting

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am doing a program where while running the program i want to copy a image from other folder and paste on the running form which has to be saved in the sql server. How to do this?

Comment: Take a bit of your time and read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems unclear. But if you are referring to copy a image from a folder to another, ones this is done we want to store this image into the sql-server.

If this is the case; you need to look at the following answer at stackoverflow (even though its for c++ the general idea is good) [c++ sql connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345110/using-odbc-to-connect-to-sql-server-2008).

Here you will write your statement for the sqlcommandline

```
    SQLHANDLE sqlevent, sqlconnection, sqlstatement;

if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlevent))
{
    //cout << "The sqlevent has failed to be created." << endl;
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}


if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlevent, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
{
    //cout << "The sqlevent has failed to be initialized." << endl;
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}

if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlevent, &sqlconnection))
{
    //cout << "The sqlconnection has failed to be created." << endl;
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//SQLWCHAR retstring[10000];
SQLWCHAR retstring[10000];

SQLDriverConnect(sqlconnection,
    NULL,
    L"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=serveradress.something.something;DATABASE=dbname;Trusted Connection=Yes",
    SQL_NTS,
    retstring,
    1024,
    NULL,
    SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlconnection, &sqlstatement))
{
    //cout << "The sqlstatement has failed to be created." << endl;
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}


commandline = L"BULK INSERT Test.dbo.Orders FROM 'C:/RAW/picture.jpg' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ';')";

if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlstatement, (SQLWCHAR*)commandline, SQL_NTS))
{
    //cout << "The import sql command has failed to execute." << endl;
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
//SQLExecDirect(sqlstatement, (SQLWCHAR*)commandline, SQL_NTS);
// EVENTUELLT LÄGGA TILL ATT RADERA FILEN FRÅN SIN PLATS?

// SQLHANDLE sqlevent, sqlconnection, sqlstatement;

SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatement);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnection);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlevent);  //End the connection
```

So in short, copy and paste the code and change depending on which program you are using. Then write in commandline = "insert tablename from 'C:/RAW/picture.jpg'" and loop for all the pictures that you want to insert.

Hope this helps somewhat. But please rewrite the question if I have not answered your question at all before voting, so we can help you even more.

Comment: Seriously? Did you see the tag VB.NET?

Comment: Yea, totally missed that. I apologize. Great point @Steve. Should i just remove my answer?

Comment: Yes, well you could wait a bit to see if the OP understand your code and could translate it to something useful, but given the generic and unclear statement expressed in the question I suppose that this is not the case.

Comment: When I run my program window should appear where I can copy and paste images by clicking icons(copy, paste)