# SQL.H and SQLEXT.H not found in ODBC program in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, odbc, header-files

Hi am trying to ues ODBC connection in c using following code.But i was not able to find the header file for **SQL.H and SQLEXT.H**.It was even not found in the installed Include folder.Where to find the source for these two headers or is there any site available for downloading the header file.???

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sql.h>
 #include <sqlext.h>
```

Error is **unable to find SQL.H**

Comment: Have you installed unixodbc-dev ?

Comment: @Thiyagarajan is it necessary to install unixodbc-dev ..??

Comment: Yes those headers are provided by unixodbc-dev

Comment: @Thiyagarajan i found download from http://www.unixodbc.org/download.html this link but it seems to be support for linux ...But i need to work on windows

Comment: Think this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345110/using-odbc-to-connect-to-sql-server-2008

Comment: They are standard header files in the Windows SDK.  Why you don't have them is impossible to guess, be sure to use a project template to get started.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql.h header file missing though unixODBC is installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447386/sql-h-header-file-missing-though-unixodbc-is-installed)

Answer (score 2):

sql.h and sqlext.h is part of **Windows SDK**. Windows SDK is installed after installation of Visual Studio or it's possible to download Windows SDK separately - SDK is free.
For example, I have these files here - it depends on SDK version:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include\sqlext.h"
```

Also check whether your C++ project settings has correct reference to Win SDK

[image]

Comment: In my case, the folder was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include`, but this got me looking in the right place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows SDK installed under Windows 8.1 or 10, then take a look under

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\..."
```

or

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\..."
```

include the following:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
```